# How to get gulp-html-minifier's output into gulp-inject-stringified-html?

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to use these two gulp plugins together:

- [gulp-html-minifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-minifier)
- [gulp-inject-stringified-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject-stringified-html)

Or put differently, I'm trying to inject the contents of files containing html fragments into my javascript files after they're minified.

When I'm trying to run a straight up `gulp` build I get this:

> `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\path\to\.temp\template.html'`

Here's a **repro** of my situation. My folder structure:

```
/src/app.js
/src/template.html
/gulpfile.js
/package.json
```

My `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var injectHtml = require('gulp-inject-stringified-html');
var htmlmin = require('gulp-html-minifier');

gulp.task('minify', [], function() {
    gulp.src('src/*.html')
        .pipe(htmlmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.temp'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['minify'], function() {
    gulp.src('src/*.js')
        .pipe(injectHtml())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.build'));
});
```

The `template.html` file:

```html
<div>My Template</div>
```

The `app.js` file:

```
var html = { gulp_inject: "../.temp/template.html" };
```

Now, if I run `minify` manually first, things will work as expected. From this I speculate I'm not using Gulp correctly. I reckon I'd need to pipe the result of `htmlmin` into the `injectHtml` method. But I fail to see how.

How can I get these two plugins to play together nicely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a return in the minify task. It should look like that:

```
gulp.task('minify', [], function() {
    return gulp.src('src/*.html')
        .pipe(htmlmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.temp'));
});
```

Without return, the default task doesn't have any way to know that minify finished, so it may start before the minified html file was created.